# Unable to alternate colours in Material UI Datagrid v5 Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to achieve alternate colouring in my Material UI datagrid(1 row being blue other white) but am not able to do so. I am using Material UI v5 for Reactjs.

Table.js

```
import * as React from "react";

import { DataGrid,gridClasses } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

import "./style.css";

export default function DataTable(props) {


  return (
    <div style={{}}style={{ height: 585, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid
        style={{ letterSpacing: "1px" }}
        rows={props.rows}
        columns={props.columns}
        pageSize={5}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
        // getRowClassName={(params) => `super-app-theme--${params.row.status}`}
        getRowClassName={(params) =>
          params.indexRelativeToCurrentPage % 2 === 0 ? 'blue' : 'black'
        }


        // checkboxSelection
        sx={{
          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
          fontSize: '14px',     
          fontWeight: '550',
          color: "black",
          backgroundColor: "#FAF9F6",
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried using the getRowClassName parameter with the indexRelativeToCurrentPage but with no effect. Any help regarding this is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this problem by creating a new DataGrid by using styled components.

MUI X has a demo on it is documentation. Check the [Striped rows](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/style/#StripedGrid.js)